# Event Detection

Tags: machine-learning

Can someone explain what is Event Detection? What activities or events fall under the purview of event detection? I have searched for some definitions but I am unable to understand. Are events like accident detection, waving hands, building collapse come under event detection?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this without knowing in what context you encountered the phrase.  I don't think you're going to find a standard meaning that is accepted across all of computer science.  Perhaps you should ask whoever used that phrase with you what they meant by it.

Comment: In a project, I have a role to collect data on Event Detection but I don't know what kind of events fall under the purview of event detection so I am asking if there are particular events in it or it is a general term for all kind of events as I mentioned in my question

Comment: Rather than answering with comments, we'd like you to [edit] your question so it provides all the necessary background and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  We want the question to be understandable without having to read the comments.  Comments exist only to help you improve the question; after they have served their purpose, please flag them as 'no longer needed'.  Thank you!

Comment: If someone assigned you a role, you need to talk to them about what they mean.  Asking here isn't going to be suitable, because we can't guess what they might have in their mind, and in the end it doesn't matter what we say; if you do what we say but it isn't what they want, it still won't be acceptable.  So, I don't think this question is answerable or suitable here.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) to see if that fits what you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for giving your precious time and advice